# installing STS 3.7.2 64 bit on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: tomcat, spring-tool-suite

I can install but the pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.1.2.RELEASE will not be installable. It doesn't show up when you first open STS, if you try to add it the error is "The .tc-runtime-instance file is missing". which is not the filename is named tcruntime-instance.sh  or .bat

I am sure I downloaded correctly.

Has anyone else had this issue?

Is there a workaround ?

Answer (score 0):

The message "The .tc-runtime-instance file is missing" is for the server instance and not for the server runtime. When a new server instance named X is created you should see /X folder under which .tc-runtime-instance file must be located. In your case this file is missing... Probably because instance is just not being created.
Perhaps 3.1.2 pivotal tc server is not installed correctly. Did you install a brand new STS 3.7.2? Or did you upgrade it from a previous version and installed tc server 3.1.2 separately? If you've installed tc server separately then ensure you create the "Server Runtime" for tc server 3.1.2 installation correctly. Go to Preferences -> Server -> Runtime Environment preference page. On that page click the "Add..." button, name the runtime and most importantly point to the 3.1.2 tc server installation folder.
Once the server runtime is created, make sure you select this runtime on the first page of Create Server Instance wizard. There must be "Server Runtime Environment" drop down at the bottom of the first page of the wizard.
Hope this helps!